# How to display points defined via latitude and longitude on a Bubble Map?

Tags: looker-studio

```
SELECT
  name,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  CONCAT(latitude,',',longitude) AS location
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_m.ghcnm_tavg_stations`
LIMIT
  1000
```

I'd like to display those stations on a Bubble Map in Data Studio.

But it doesn't accept `location` as the location dimension. How do I have to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange... It worked for me. I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test 
as
SELECT
  name,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  CONCAT(latitude,',',longitude) AS location
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_m.ghcnm_tavg_stations`
LIMIT
  1000
```

then used it as a datasource for the Datastudio Report.
Make sure that you selected the Type of the field as `Latitude, Longitude` and pressed `Refresh Data`
[image]
[image]